# How to create multi level menu in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a dropdown menu like the things used in admin panels, but I don't know how to do it.

like this photos from admin lte:
[Menu image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clA4c.png)
[Menu image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t03nX.png)

Can anyone help me please? I think isn't difficult.

Comment: My dear friend, I did all the possible searches and recently I asked a question here, if you were upset, you could not see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use a expansion tile for the expandable menu and the children can be just regular buttons like this, its really customizable as well, you can change the shape and colors

```
ExpansionTile(
  title: Text("My Menu"),
  children: [
    MyButton1(),
    MyButton2(),
    MyButton3(),
 )
```